# Getting most recent entries when using GROUP BY in RoR

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have a table organized in the following way:

```
id | userid | action | notes | created_at
-----------------------------------------
1  | 1      | foo    | bar   | datetime
2  | 33     | foo    | bax   | datetime
3  | 1      | foo    | okay  | datetime
4  | 3      | bam    | bad   | datetime
5  | 33     | foo    | bom   | datetime
```

What I would like to be able to do is, in Ruby on Rails, group the rows by userid but grab only the most recent entry for each group.

As it stands, I've gotten this far:

```
Thing.select("userid, notes").where(:action => "foo").order('`when` DESC')
```

Which will usually return something like:

```
 userid | notes 
 --------------
 1      | bar  
 33     | bax
```

When what I'm looking for is this:

```
 userid | notes 
 --------------
 1      | okay
 33     | bom
```

I think I copy/pasted that all right...heh. Is there a way to achieve what I'm trying to do? Without resorting to searching inside my app itself? Thanks.

**Update** Attempted the first suggestion, no dice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add .order("id desc") to the end of your line

Comment: Sorry, i didn't get your problem the first time. I had similar case once and wrote a query to do it. Only problem is the query worked fine on MySQL, then went busted when I moved to production PostgreSQL.

I went to the app back then. Not sure if there is smarter way

Comment: It's ok, I ended out fixing this by altering a different table where I don't have to nail my db with all this madness. Thanks for the effort tho!